# Behavior of Manager in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I cant find an explanation for this behavior in Python 3:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, freeze_support, Manager

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        # self._manager = Manager()
        # self._list = self._manager.list()

        manager = Manager()
        self._list = manager.list()

    def producer(self):
        processes = []
        cores = cpu_count()
        for i in range(cores):
            process = Process(target=self.worker)
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)

        for process in processes:
            process.join()

    def worker(self):
        print('I was called')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    a = A()
    a.producer()
```

With this in `__init__` :

```
    self._manager = Manager()
    self._list = self._manager.list()
```

I get an error `OSError: handle is closed` at the call `process.start()`.

With this in `__init__`:

```
    manager = Manager()
    self._list = manager.list()
```

All seems to work.

I read https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes but I can't find an explanation why an instance of a `Manager()` can't be a variable in the example above. My best guess is because `Manager()` is itself process and with a call like that `target=self.worker` I'm trying to break some logic in handling processes.

**Question:** Am I right? or I miss something?

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/files-from-server/apps/test_module/test_export.py", line 27, in <module>
    a.producer()
  File "G:/files-from-server/apps/test_module/test_export.py", line 15, in producer
    process.start()
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 939, in reduce_pipe_connection
    dh = reduction.DupHandle(conn.fileno(), access)
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 170, in fileno
    self._check_closed()
  File "c:\users\maxim\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 136, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, not just the error.

Comment: @roganjosh I added full traceback